# twitter api loads up again after post - corona sdk

Tags: ios, twitter, lua, coronasdk

So I am following the twitter api tutorial here: (http://coronalabs.com/blog/2013/02/11/using-the-ios-built-in-twitter-feature/) 
and it works and posts normally. However after I click send, twitter closes and then loads back again automatically and displays an error message on device saying " duplicate error, cannot send tweet"

How can I stop twitter loading up immediately after I post first message and stop the duplicate tweet error?

```
function tweetCallback( event )
  transition.to(twitterbtn, {time=50, y=display.contentCenterY +120 })
    if ( event.action == "cancelled" ) then
      print( "User cancelled" )
    else
      native.showPopup( "twitter", options )
      print( "Thanks for the tweet!" )
    end
end
```

--

```
local options = {
    message = " I scored "  .. utils.highscore ..  " Miles ",
    listener = tweetCallback
}
```

Button ID settings

```
function buttonPressed(event)
    local id = event.target.id
    if id == "menu" then transition.to(homebtn, {time=50, y=display.contentCenterY + 124, onComplete=gameReady})
    elseif id == "tweet" then transition.to(twitterbtn, {time=50, y=display.contentCenterY + 124,  onComplete=tweetCallback})
    elseif id == "reload" then transition.to(reloadButton, {time=50, y=display.contentCenterY + 124, onComplete=reloadGame})

    end

    return true
  end 

  homebtn.id = "menu"
  twitterbtn.id = "tweet"
  facebookButton.id = "reload"
  homebtn:addEventListener("tap", buttonPressed)
  twitterbtn:addEventListener("tap", buttonPressed) 
  reloadButton:addEventListener( "tap", buttonPressed )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the `native.showPopup( "twitter", options )` from the `tweetCallBack` function. This function is used to handle callBacks after a tweet has been send or cancelled.

You need to call the `native.showPopup( "twitter", options )` from  some other event, ex. a button click.

***ADDED:***

```
local  function tweetThis(obj)
    local options = {
        message = " I scored "  .. utils.highscore ..  " Miles ",
        listener = tweetCallback
    }

    native.showPopup( "twitter", options )
end

function buttonPressed(event)
    local id = event.target.id
    if id == "menu" then transition.to(homebtn, {time=50, y=display.contentCenterY + 124, onComplete=gameReady})
    elseif id == "tweet" then transition.to(twitterbtn, {time=50, y=display.contentCenterY + 124,  onComplete=tweetThis})
    elseif id == "reload" then transition.to(reloadButton, {time=50, y=display.contentCenterY + 124, onComplete=reloadGame})

    end

    return true
  end 

  homebtn.id = "menu"
  twitterbtn.id = "tweet"
  facebookButton.id = "reload"
  homebtn:addEventListener("tap", buttonPressed)
  twitterbtn:addEventListener("tap", buttonPressed) 
  reloadButton:addEventListener( "tap", buttonPressed )
```

Comment: Hi Frozire, thanks for the help. Could you show me an example of how you would add the popup to my buttonPressed ID function? Ive added the code to the question. With each button theres a slight animation to it, however I don't mind removing them for now.

Comment: I added some code. Keep in mind I haven't been able to test this, but this should be how it works. You click a button and initiate  the native popup with twitter. When the twitter windows is cancelled or completed it will automatically call the tweetCallback function, since you added that as a listener in the options.

Comment: Remember to accept the answer so other people can find it too.